# Uploading an mp3 to my (php based) web server from an iPhone app

Tags: php, objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm looking to upload an mp3 file from my iPhone app to a given php page. To do this I found the ASIFormDataRequest class. Now I made a piece of code in my app like so:

```
NSLog(@"fastBackwardButtonLoosened - sending the stuff");
NSString *theUrl = @"MyServerURL";//Sorry not showing this:)
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]];

[request setFile:[soundFileURL absoluteString] forKey:@"mainfile"];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"The request was sent!!");
```

However I can't figure out how to put my NSURL which points to the mp3 inside this request. I have tried the above, but couldn't find anything that points me in the right direction.. Any ideas?

The code that receives the request is like so:

```
$SafeFile = $HTTP_POST_FILES['mainfile']['name'];
$uploaddir = "uploads/";
$path = $uploaddir.$SafeFile;

if($mainfile != none){ //AS LONG AS A FILE WAS SELECTED...

    if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['mainfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){ //IF IT HAS BEEN COPIED...
        //Good
    } else {
        //Bad
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the mp3 to be uploaded a local file on the iphone?

Comment: Yes it will be located on the iphone itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
[request setFile:[soundFileURL absoluteString] forKey:@"mainfile"];
```

I think you should use `[soundFileURL path]` instead of `[soundFileURL absoluteString]`, as `[request setFile:]` expects a filepath, not a full URL.

Comment: It seems to help some as it takes longer for the request to get sent(probably becouse of the big file), but it still won't copy it to the uploads/ folder as it's supposed to.. It seems the $SafeFile is empty right before the first if statement in the php code.