# Uploading an mp3 to my server from my iPhone app

Tags: php, objective-c

It seems i have solved the first in a set of problems with my code. The question I am talking about is this one: [First Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6594582/703595). As you can see the given answer is only about the objective-c code. This appears to be working correctly right now.

The problem seems to be the php code not finding the file as `$HTTP_POST_FILES['mainfile']['name']` returns null. I'm not sure if the problem lies within the php code or the objective-c code. Both are below:

**Objective-C code**

```
NSString *theUrl = @"MyServerURL";//Sorry not showing this:)
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]];

[request setFile:[soundFileURL path] forKey:@"mainfile"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

**PHP code**

```
$SafeFile = $HTTP_POST_FILES['mainfile']['name'];

$uploaddir = "uploads/";
$path = $uploaddir.$SafeFile;
$mainfile = $HTTP_POST_FILES['mainfile'];

$toWrite .= "\nThe path to which the file should be saved = " . $path . "\n";

if($mainfile != null){ //AS LONG AS A FILE WAS SELECTED...
    $toWrite .= "The file is NOT NONE!\n";

    if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['mainfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){ //IF IT HAS BEEN COPIED...
        $toWrite .= "The file was succesfully saved to the server! \n";
    }
}
```

This `$toWrite` variable gets written to a txt file. In this file i can see that at the first `$toWrite` the `$SafeFile` seems to be empty. This led me to beleve that the file is not accessable or not sent at all..

If anyone can help me figure out this problem I would be most thankfull!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`['name']` can be empty. It's not required that uploaded files cary a `filename=` value. And regardless of that you should never use it *unfiltered*, as that opens the door to path traversal exploits.

Your second problem might be the use of `$HTTP_POST_FILES`, which was valid in PHP4. Nowadays that array is called [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.files.php). To see if your upload succeeded at all and what descriptive fields are present, test with `print_r($_FILES);` before you try anything else.

Comment: the print_r($_FILES) indicates that there is 1 file in the array (as there is supposed to be). But i need to have the filename in a variable to put it in the database. Any idea as how to do this?

And this is only a test, ik now i have to filter :)

Comment: Does it show a `[name]` entry? If there is none, then you can't use it. Or you need to adapt your obj-c code.